# I want to print inverted delta in LaTex

Tags: equations, symbols, greek, mathtools

Inverted delta for representing gradient
how to do that?
i didnt find a command

I know to print using `\delta` but cant represent gradient.

Answer (score 6):

You get the inverter delta with `\nabla`. In general, when you’re looking for a symbol, you may find http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html helpful.